# I'm having trouble deploying my flutter project due to firebase dependencies

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to set up firebase for both android and ios. I've tried using different versions in pubspec.yaml, but i'm still getting errors like this. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\13363\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\354fc33358371181aa1b0a8e262a9145\jetified-play-services-auth-16.0.1\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml:9: AAPT: error: resource drawable/googleg_standard_color_18 (aka com.example.catbox:drawable/googleg_standard_color_18) not found.

     C:\Users\13363\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\354fc33358371181aa1b0a8e262a9145\jetified-play-services-auth-16.0.1\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18 (aka com.example.catbox:drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18) not found.

     C:\Users\13363\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\354fc33358371181aa1b0a8e262a9145\jetified-play-services-auth-16.0.1\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml:9: AAPT: error: resource drawable/googleg_standard_color_18 (aka com.example.catbox:drawable/googleg_standard_color_18) not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s

The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Finished with error: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Comment: The error you have provided clearly states that a drawable resource is not found. This has nothing to do with AndroidX libraries. I would verify if these resources actually exist and what is needing them. Make sure the XML files are valid and try to execute invalidate cache/restart.

Comment: run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` and finally run your project